# Update MySQL using HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a form which allows you to update a database table using php.
I'm kinda new to PHP so excuse me if I make a stupid mistake in the code.

This is my edit.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cats");

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<?php 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

$name = $row['name'];
$email = $row['email'];
$rank = $row['rank'];
$birth = $row['birth'];
$joined = $row['joined'];
$steamid = $row['steamid'];
?>


<td width="100"></td>
<td><?=$name?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Email</td>
<td><input name="emailid" type="text" value="<?=$email?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Rank</td>
<td><input name="rankid" type="text" value="<?=$rank?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Birth</td>
<td><input name="birthid" type="text" value="<?=$birth?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Joined</td>
<td><input name="joinedid" type="text" value="<?=$joined?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Steamid</td>
<td><input name="steamidid" type="text" value="<?=$steamid?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

$name = $row['nameid'];
$email = $row['emailid'];
$rank = $row['rankid'];
$birth = $row['birthid'];
$joined = $row['joinedid'];
$steamid = $row['steamidid'];

$update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cats SET email = '$email', rank = '$rank', birth = '$birth', joined = '$joined', steamid = '$steamid' WHERE name = '$name';");

$retval = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cats SET email = '$email', rank = '$rank', birth = '$birth', joined = '$joined', steamid = '$steamid' WHERE name = '$name';");
if (!$update) {
    echo "Could not update data: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the table and information but the updating isn't working.

```
Updated data successfully
```

I've checked the database but it's not updating anything.

Comment: The "updated data successfully" message is not conditional so it will print whenever the form is submitted. Wrap it in "else".

Comment: Look now, you were wrong updating your data.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dear i think you change the record based on **Name** because you can use $name in where clause and you can also change the **Name** than never true where clause so that your query execute successfully but not effected on any of the row.

> you want to get for editable record and that's unique id base update row it will defiantly work.

Answer (score 0):

**Informations:**

With `mysqli_error()` you need to write about which connection you want to get errors, like this:

```
mysqli_error($con);
```

With `mysqli_query()` you need to give two parameters, `connection` and `query` like this:

```
$update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cats SET email = '$email', rank = '$rank', birth = '$birth', joined = '$joined', steamid = '$steamid' WHERE name = '$name';");
```

**How to debug:**

If you want to check that `UPDATE` query return any error you can do something like this:

```
if (!$update) {
    echo "Could not update data: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

You can try to debug your query with something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE cats SET email = '$email', rank = '$rank', birth = '$birth', joined = '$joined', steamid = '$steamid' WHERE name = '$name';";
echo $sql; // this output write in your phpMyadmin to check if there are any errors.
$update = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**Other problem we got:**

**1.** I think also you should have `else` in your code, f.ex.:

```
if (!$update) {
    echo "Could not update data: " . mysqli_error($con);
} else {
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
```

**2.** You are not getting data from `$_POST` it should be like:

```
$name = $_POST['nameid']; // not $row['nameid']
$email = $_POST['emailid'];
$rank = $_POST['rankid'];
$birth = $_POST['birthid'];
$joined = $_POST['joinedid'];
$steamid = $_POST['steamidid'];
```

**More about used functions:**

[PHP: mysqli::$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

[PHP: mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

In your case it is **Procedural style**

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not fully working.I've updated the code.

Comment: Is it updating in your database anyway?

Comment: No it's not updating anything in the database

Comment: Check last part of my answer, try that output from `echo` write to your phpmyadmin to check if there is any error.

Comment: And why are you calling two times update with `$update` and `$retval`?

Comment: It think I might know why it isn't working. 
It's showing all of the records.
https://gyazo.com/1071b92bfd924068c37250ca1f3aacba
Updated data successfully UPDATE cats SET email = '', rank = '', birth = '', joined = '', steamid = '' WHERE name = ''; That's what it shows after presssing the update button

Comment: In your case if you will try to update first person with your form it will always update last one, because in your `while` loop your variables: `$name = $row['name'];
$email = $row['email'];
$rank = $row['rank'];
$birth = $row['birth'];
$joined = $row['joined'];
$steamid = $row['steamid'];` are set as last row fetched from database. So if you will try to edit Matt it will work, with other, not really, because of variables which are set on Matt.

Comment: I've tried updating matt but that doesn't work.Updated data successfully UPDATE cats SET email = '', rank = '', birth = '', joined = '', steamid = '' WHERE name = '';

Comment: Now it seems like in your `$_POST` table is nothing.

Comment: Change your code to `UPDATE` once, not twice, and check errors then.

Comment: Check now, you were not getting data to `UPDATE` from `$_POST`, you `UPDATED` data with data you fetched from SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP PDO database access functions, your code as it stands is vulnerable to SQL-Injection! PDO will also make debugging and working with the database much easier.

I think your check for "update" in $_POST is not working because update is not a field inside your form but the submit button itself, try to check for one of the fields instead.